# Oracle Anonymous Block Call in Shell Script

Tags: oracle, shell, block, anonymous

I have a shell script, which will call a function in he DB to get a return value.  This is pretty straight forward.  SELECT {function_name} FROM dual;

However, the function also updates a column if certain criteria is true.  As such, I cannot call this function in a query mode because it performs DML.

My question is: From the shell script, how can I code an anonymous block (DECLARE...BEGIN...RETURN...END), and return the value to the shell script.   This will get around the DML issue which prevents me from calling it in a SELECT statement.

Many thanks!